# how to show hidden folder at Dirlistbox vb6?

Tags: vb6

I have a hidden folder , and I use VB6 to make a program for get the all folder on a drive and show at DirListBox , but it just only show non-hidden folder only , what I want is show all hidden or non-hidden folder at dirlistbox for this drive , so who can help me ?

Comment: The DirListBox doesn't show hidden folders unless the Show hidden folders oprion is selected . If you want to show hidden folders you should use something like the TreeView control and the Dir$ function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could go here
http://www.mvps.org/ccrp/

and use this >> FolderTreeview
but if you cannot see your hidden files and folders it may be that you will have to change the folder options on your PC?
hope this helps

Comment: That web link is no longer valid. The CCRP project was discontinued many years ago although the pages are still available at [link](http://ccrp.mvps.org/).

Comment: I try open the http://www.mvps.org/ccrp/ link but it show me 404 - File or directory not found.

Comment: My Idea is show all file including hidden files and folders on the dir list box without change any setting on the windows pc , cus this program I design is for management to manage the employee computer for database file location setting and user cannot see or any database file or folder on their computer without my program